# CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE: empty/missing DT_HASH error

Tags: android, gcc, compiler-errors, android-ndk

I cross-compiled an ARM binary executable and transferred to my Android device and set permissions. But when I try to execute it returns this error `CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE: empty/missing DT_HASH in "./hello_world" (built with --hash-style=gnu?)`

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I transferred the binary to my device via FTP (FileZilla) and had transfer type set to Auto. This corrupted the binary resulting in the error. When I transferred with Binary transfer type, the binary executed fine on my device.